# Apple Mail sending new mails from both mailboxes

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, imap

I'm using Apple Mail on Mavericks (10.9.2).

I've configured two mailboxes, both gmail accounts using IMAP.

My problem is that every time I compose and send a new email it sends the same email from both accounts regardless of which account I select in the drop-down. I have my preferences set to Send new messages from: Account of selected mailbox.

Comment: Please explain how do you know it sends a duplicate email from both accounts.

Comment: Try the more forceful method, in mail settings- Account-Outgoing mail server (select) + (check) Use only this server.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I know because I see the email in the "sent mails" of both mailboxes in the client and also when I sign into gmail from the browser.
The options in Account-Outgoing mail server are gmail and gmail(offline). But this option is available for both mailboxes. Which one should i select?